# SwiftKey 3 9-key keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, swiftkey

Has anyone been able to find and activate 9-key keyboard for swiftkey 3? The qwerty in portrait mode is killing me it's not possible always to type in landscape mode.

Comment: Why downvote? It's a good question. Not everyone has small dingers

Comment: Not everyone types with their dingers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. SwiftKey doesn't have a 9-key mode.

Comment: Oh. Any hope for guys like me with big fingers?

Comment: If you want to use swiftkey than try setting the key height in advanced or get a bigger phone. If other keyboards are fine than try 'thumb keyboard'.

Comment: The phone is Galaxy S2 :). I will try that trick with the height. Will get back to you

Comment: you could try ToucPal Keyboard:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cootek.smartinputv5